# R use of '\' in a string

Tags: r, backslash

I am experiment with R and came across an issue I don't fully understand.

```
dates = c("03-19-76", "04/19/76", as.character("04\19\76"), "05.19.76", "060766")
dates
```

> [1] "03-19-76" "04/19/76" **"04\0019>"** "05.19.76" "060766"

Why should the third date be interpreted and what sort of interpretation is taking place.  I also got this output when I left out the as.character function.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Quotes.html)

Comment: If I understood correctly, backslash characters need to be escaped

   `dates = c("03-19-76", "04/19/76", "05.19.76", "060766", "04\\07\\13")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Echoing the comments, make sure to escape backslashes in strings.

```
dates = c("03-19-76", "04/19/76", "04\\19\\76", "05.19.76", "060766")

> dates
[1] "03-19-76"   "04/19/76"   "04\\19\\76" "05.19.76"   "060766"
```

Now that you've got the dates stored, there's actually a lot of built in functions you can use with dates. Dates even have their own object types! To do so use `as.Date`. Since you're using nonstandard date formats, you have to tell R how you've formatted them.

```
> as.Date(dates[1], "%m-%d-%y")
[1] "1976-03-19"

> as.Date(dates[2], "%m/%d/%y")
[1] "1976-04-19"

> as.Date("20\\10\\1999", "%d\\%m\\%Y")
[1] "1999-10-20"

a <- as.Date(dates[1], "%m-%d-%y")
b <- as.Date(dates[2], "%m/%d/%y")

> b - a
Time difference of 31 days

d <- as.numeric(b-a)

> d
[1] 31

> a + d^2
[1] "1978-11-05"
```

Note that since you're using 2-digit years, you use %y. If you used 4-digit years, you'd use %Y. If you forget, you'll get oddities like this:

```
> as.Date("03/14/2001", "%m/%d/%y")
[1] "2020-03-14"

> as.Date("03/14/10", "%m/%d/%Y")
[1] "0010-03-14"
```

Comment: I would like to add  
    
`date = "20\\10\\1999"`    
`as.Date(date, format="%d\\%m\\%Y")`

Comment: Added! Anything else I can do to answer your question?